# How could an element of a real segment $]-r,r[$ NOT be a limit point of the segment?

Tags: general-topology, power-series

Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis* states

[image: picture]

Doesn't the fact that $S$ be a segment of $\mathbb{R}$ by definition imply that every point of $S$ is a limit point of $S$? If this is the case, how could there be an element $x\in S$ such that $x$ is **not** a limit point of $S$?

Comment: Yes, every point of $S$ is a limit point of $S$, but that’s not the issue. The issue is whether the set $E$ has a limit point in $S$. For instance, if $E$ is finite, then it does not have any limit point in $S$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But isn't $E$ a subset of $S$? I don't usderstand how that isn't contradictory

Comment: Suppose that $E=\{0\}$; no matter what $R$ is, $E$ is a subset of $S$. But there is no $x\in S$ that is a limit point of $E$, so $E$ has no limit point in $S$. In fact, $E$ has no limit point at all. Remember, $p$ is a limit point of $E$ iff every open interval containing $p$ contains a point of $E\setminus\{p\}$, and for $E=\{0\}$ there is no $p\in S$ with that property.

Comment: Wow, I understood that *$E$ has a limit point in $S$* meant that one of the points in $E$ was a limit point of $S$. Sorry for the silly question... Is this type of misunderstanding usual or am I just stupid?

Comment: Not stupid: it can take a while to get used to technical language and the way that it’s used. No need to apologize: given your misunderstanding, it was a perfectly reasonable question, and by getting the misunderstanding cleared up, it served a useful purpose.